# emacs move forward by n commas

Tags: emacs

Can anyone advise how I can move forward (or back) by *n* commas in emacs?

I am trying to navigate my way through a CSV file

I am aware I can do something like:

`C-u 100 M-f`

but being able to do something more reg-exp like specifically on commas would be more accurate

Comment: If you are interested in testing `elisp`, this would be an excellent exercise. In that case, let me know and I can give you a few pointers.

Comment: do you mean writing a function in my .emacs file? if so it would be a first for me but certainly interested in having a go. The other thing I tried was combining C-u # and C-s , but that didn't work

Comment: Yes, in `.emacs`, or in a module by itself. In the Help menu there are both an elisp introduction and a reference guide. You will need something like `(defun my-skip-commas (arg) (interactive "p") ... 'arg' contains the value of C-u ... you code goes here ...)`. You will need to loop `arg` times, each time search for a comma, which you could do with `(search-forward "," nil t)`. Give it a try, if you don't manage to pull it together, I will help you out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> The other thing I tried was combining C-u # and C-s , but that didn't work

It will with a keyboard macro, which you can define interactively.

- <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>(</kbd> -- start recording
- <kbd>C-s</kbd><kbd>,</kbd><kbd>RET</kbd> -- search for a comma (the `RET` is important; see below)
- <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>)</kbd> -- stop recording

You can now execute that macro again with <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>e</kbd> (and then just <kbd>e</kbd> for continued single repetitions), or use a prefix argument to repeat it a given number of times:

<kbd>C-u</kbd> `100` <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>e</kbd>

Keyboard macros are tremendously useful, and can be easily bound to keys, or even added to your .emacs file in elisp form if you want to keep one for future use. [See the manual for details](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Keyboard-Macros.html).

edit:

More seamlessly for ad-hoc macros, you can supply the prefix argument when you stop the recording to get exactly that many repetitions, including the one used to record it:
<kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>(</kbd><kbd>C-s</kbd><kbd>,</kbd><kbd>RET</kbd><kbd>C-u</kbd> `100` <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>)</kbd>

I was seeing some unexpected behaviour with that sequence before I added the <kbd>RET</kbd> to explicitly invoke `isearch-exit` before stopping recording. It behaved as if it was only recording and repeating the comma key (leading to the comma being *inserted* many times instead of being searched for many times).

Using `edit-last-kbd-macro` after recording, I could see there was a quirk when using isearch in a macro, such that the `C-x` typed when stopping the recording is actually included in the macro definition, which was presumably causing the problem for this particular method of invocation. Similarly with the alternate <kbd>F3</kbd> and <kbd>F4</kbd> bindings (in that case, `F4` ends up in the definition). I don't know whether this is a bug or a feature, but apparently it pays to exit the isearch before stopping the macro recording!

p.s. Although the two sets of macro recording bindings aren't identical in *all* respects, everything here also works with `F3` and `F4`, so for this example you could slightly more concisely use <kbd>F3</kbd><kbd>C-s</kbd><kbd>,</kbd><kbd>RET</kbd><kbd>C-u</kbd> `100` <kbd>F4</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

With
[`iy-go-to-char`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/iy-go-to-char.el) you
can do <kbd>M-3</kbd><kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>f</kbd><kbd>,</kbd> to go to
the third comma.

Comment: I've reimplemented iy-go-to-char on top of isearch for lazy match highlighting and various other improvements.  Comments welcome.  https://github.com/lewang/jump-char

Answer (score 1):

Use [CSV mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/csv-mode.el) which will give you convenient functions to do what you want and more

Answer (score 0):

You could record a macro with *C-u C-u M-f* or *C-u C-u C-f* and use that.  If it's infrequently used, record it using *PF3* and play it back by pressing *PF4*.